# The difference between "3 way Merge Sort" and "3 way Natural Merge Sort"

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, natural-sort, 3-way-merge

I am trying to learn all the merge sort algorithms. I tried to search the web for them but each page says something different and I want closure regarding those algorithms.

Can anybody help?

Comment: `trying to learn all the merge sort algorithms` anything else you intend to devote your life to? `each [web] page says something different` well, this is going to be number n+1.

Comment: this might answer you http://www.home.hs-karlsruhe.de/~pach0003/informatik_1/aufgaben/en/doc/de/hska/java/exercises/sorting/NaturalMergeSort.html

Comment: Seems like the tags answer your question. Did you read the tag info for `natural-sort`?

Comment: @greybeard you could stop being sarcastic and answer the question from the title if you know the answer. And no I am not devoting my life to learning those algorithms. In comparison with your brilliant mind and responses my limited knowledge at this point has information about only 4 merge sort algorithms, though I bet there are much more out there:). What I know for the moment about natural merge sort is that in comparison with the simple one when it divides the numbers in groups he takes the already sorted segments as entire groups. All I want is closure, to know if I am right or not:).